# Showing Edits on Answers

Tags: discussion

I think we should display edits or maybe give some kind of credit to original answerer.  I answered a question that had a poor answer with my recommendation, which was very different, then the original poster edited their answer and stole my idea.  I could see how recognizing this systematically might be difficult, but there should be some kind of path to report this.  That answer has since gotten a lot more votes.  I will get a link to the post and put it here.

Here is the post I'm referring to:  [How to tell my manager that I don't want to be scrum master](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/107974/how-to-tell-my-manager-that-i-dont-want-to-be-scrum-master/107985#107985)

Comment: Were you still planning on posting the link?

Comment: I'm really confused, Stacy... edits *do* show in the edit history. If someone is plagiarizing you, report it. But without an example of what you're talking about, I don't think we can really understand what you're asking.

Comment: When I originally looked at the answer to the question posted above it had a big dialog on what the person wanted from their future career.  It was terrible advice so I posted a different answer, then the primary answerer did a major revision and took out most of what they said about talking about what's important for that employee, consistent with my answer.

Comment: Stacy, none of the answers on that question have ever been edited. Look at your question... you see where it says "edited X minutes ago"? That's where it links to all of the edits that a post has gone through. Neither of the other answers there have been edited and the top, accepted answer is older than yours.

Comment: And I should clarify - when I said show edits - I meant with crossed out words or new additions being highlighted.  Otherwise, if the post is significantly edited it should appear under other posts that are earlier.

Comment: **Link: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/107974/44274**

Comment: That's what I am saying.  The accepted answer is older than mine, but it was edited after I made my post to reflect similar ideas.  If you have an audit trail, dig it up.

Comment: As  @Catija said, there aren't any edits. What are you talking about?

Comment: If it really was edited it would show `edited x minutes/hours/days ago` that you could click on and see all the edits. What you're suggesting already exists as a feature. Like Catija said, no other answer in that post has been edited.

Comment: No, it was not edited. That's not possible. If it were edited, it would show an edit history.

Comment: You keep saying that you don't see the edited links... then show us what you do see. Take a screenshot of this question and show us the "edited" not being there... if it's not there, that's a bug and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'm referring to the answer @Catija, not the question.  It appears edited shows only when you add text but not when something is deleted.  In this case the post was shortened severely.  Don't get mad at me for how your site works though, or that I'm trying to improve it, that's uncalled for.

Comment: That's not correct. Removing content only will **also** show an edit history. Any edit made after five minutes of the post being live on the site shows in the edit history page and marks the post as "edited". But now I think you're just sort of messing with me, because you first said they stole your answer, not "made it shorter"... if all they did was clear out content that was extra, then they didn't change their answer to your answer, they just cleared out fluff.

Answer (score 10):

What you are asking about already exists.

It's an edit history page and it tracks all of the edits to a post that were made outside the initial five minute edit window of a post being made.

[Here's a timeline link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/107978/timeline) to the answer you're talking about and below is what you'll see there (as of right now).

[image: Image from link]

As you can see, there's no indication of an edit.

And here is the [edit history of that page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/107978/revisions), which (when there aren't any edits) is a hidden link that you can get to if you know where to look:

[image: Edit history page for answer in question]

And, again, you can see that the answer has never been edited.

From your question here, [look at this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/307810/revisions), it shows that the post has been edited:

[image: Question edit history link]

And if you click on it, you can see the edits to the post, just like what you're asking for:

[image: Edits to posts]

Everything is right there and obvious. There's no secret editing happening, you're just remembering incorrectly.

Comment: No I'm not remembering incorrectly, but thanks for the nice comment Catija.  On my view there are no "edited" last statistics, and I've had my answers edited with no special note that was done, except for a comment.  Maybe you are looking at some administrator view?  The original post on that thread took up a whole screen and now is very short, so maybe it was deletes only.

Comment: Nope. You're just wrong. I have no "administrator view" of questions or answers on TWP. I barely even have any reputation there. Just look at the links for yourself. Are you honestly saying that there's not an "[edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiCiv.png)" link on your question right now?

Answer (score 7):

None of the 3 answers under [that question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/107974/44274) show any edits whatsoever currently.

The [accepted answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/107978/44274), which I think is similar to [yours](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/107985/44274) is much older than yours, and like we said, there is no edit on that at all. If it were edited, it would show a link "edited x mins/hours/ ago", and the link would show you what changes were made.

So it's not possible that they copied your ideas.